# How to convert an array into list of arrays of some size in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, list

How to convert an array into list of arrays of some size in C#?

For example:

```
 byte[] incoming = {1,2,3,4};
 List<byte[]> chunks = new List<byte[]>;
```

What I'm trying to get is something like this, get a chunk of some size, here below I used 2.

```
 chunks[0] = {1,2};
 chunks[1] = {3,4};
```

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: By "long array" do you mean an array of type `long` or an array with many items? :)

Comment: Sorry for confusing description, here I used to describe the length. But the type is byte here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This helper method should make things easier:

```
public static byte[] Partial(byte[] source, int start, int length)
{
    byte[] b = new byte[length];
    Array.Copy(source, start, b, 0, length);
    return b;
}
```

From there, you can do something like:

```
for (int index = 0; index < incoming.Length; index += 2)
{
    List.Add(Partial(incoming, index, 2));
}
```

Comment: You could just use something like the latter part to add to a list returning `new byte[] {incoming[index],incoming[index+1]}` . Also, if you need an array, then you just use `listvar.ToArray()` to get the array at the end.

Comment: Thanks! Since Performance is important, I will go with this.

Comment: Thanks David! Thanks for the tips.